# Как сделать автоматическое создание субдоменов с условиями

Tags: php

Нужно не только создать поддомен на автомате, но и каким то образом загрузить в данную папку cms.

Возможно ли осуществить данный функционал не создавая реальных папок под субдомены, т.е. не грузить постоянно cms, а пользоваться одной и при помощи mysql выводить на каждый запрос-обращение к субдомену нужный сайт?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. В настройках веб-сервера (в моём случае был apache ) указать ServerAlias *.domain.com(Ваш домен). Получаем что все под домены ссылаются на основной домен. После чего на основном домене в index.php перехватываем какой $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] и в зависимости от под домена выдаём требуемый контент. Как я понял список создаваемых под доменов будет где то храниться(в БД), делайте проверку на существование под домена, в случае его отсутствия выдавайте header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

Comment: А как реализовать на самом сайте форму через которую и будут создаваться эти субдомены?

Comment: На каком уровне Ваши знания php?

Comment: Можно сказать на нулевых.

Comment: @Teorgeml, вы не хотите управлять этим через свой сайт. Поверьте. Вероятность нахождения этой формы не так уж и высока, но с лихвой компенсируется теоретическим геморроем и появлением поражающей воображение порно-рекламы на сайте.

Comment: @Teorgeml но вообще в сети есть много примеров как сделать так, чтобы xxx.site.com и yyy.site.com ссылались на папи xxx и yyy соответственно, тогда при создании такйо папки она автоматически будет подхватываться

Comment: Тогда мой Вам совет - не заморачивайтесь пока с такими сложностями.
Для реализации подобной системы требуется система регистрации/авторизации пользователей( всем подряд предоставлять такой доступ чревато клепанием всякой гадости на базе Вашей системы). Также хотя бы простенькая CMS (что то же должно висеть на этих под доменах) . Ну и дальше уже по обстоятельствам. Начинайте с азов и уроков для начинающих и всё у Вас получиться со временем.